# Octopus deploy find and replace failing

Tags: octopus-deploy

I have the following search pattern in Find and Replace step in Octopus Deploy and getting the following error. Can anyone help what this could be?

```
#{InstallDirectory}\**\*.js; #{InstallDirectory}\wwwroot\assets\config\app-settings.json
```

error message;

```
Calamari.exe : OperationStopped: The segment '**' can only appear once, as a directory name, in the glob expression 
August 17th 2020 10:30:27Error
At C:\Octopus\Work\20200817093020-15387-50\Bootstrap.ps1:38 char:1 
August 17th 2020 10:30:27Error
+ &  "${env:TentacleHome}\Calamari\9.0.3\Calamari.exe" run-script -sens ...
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you email support@octopus.com? This may require more information and logs to troubleshoot.